# What would be the use of a gettext_noop function in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, localization, internationalization, gettext

My question is about gettext itself, i kinda don't see the use of a gettext_noop function. I know what it does, but what are the benefits?

If i mark a text with e.g. gettext_noop(), it will not be translated, but xgettext can recognize it, and translation takes place when i output the string as a variable.

Is this because memory usage, or what? Is it better to use it in PHP, or just use _() (or gettext())?

Answer (score 1):

The [Gettext manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Special-cases.html#Special-cases) covers nicely the way `gettext_noop` may be useful when programming in C.

In PHP, however, it doesn't seem to make sense to do:

```php
$options = array( gettext_noop("one string"),
           gettext_noop("another string") ,);
echo _($options[0]);
```

It should be perfectly ok to do:

```php
$options = array( _("one string") ,
           _("another string"), );
echo $options[0];
```

Since PHP is a dynamically typed language, we'd need to be a lot more creative to find a good use for `gettext_noop`. Most likely, you won't need it in PHP.

That's probably the reason gettext_noop doesn't exist in a vanilla installation and doesn't even figure in [PHP's manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.gettext.php).

Comment: That's not a very good reason not to be in the php manual, now is it?

Comment: @TimoHuovinen What would be a good reason? Perhaps you mean I should emphasize that it doesn't _exist_ in a vanilla installation either?

Comment: oh, yes, the wording makes it seem as if that function actually exists within vanilla php, but I see you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

## A use-case for `gettext_noop`

It can be useful in certain situations. For instance, let's say you've got an array of allowed values for a drop-down in a form:

```
$allowed_values = ["red", "orange", "blue"];
```

In the form, you want the user to see the translated values, but for the request to submit the untranslated values:

```
<select name="color">
<?php foreach ($allowed_values as $allowed_value) : ?>
    <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($allowed_value) ?>">
        <?= htmlspecialchars(_($allowed_value)) ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Unfortunately, `xgettext` can't find the translatable strings, because they haven't been marked. You can mark them like this:

```
$allowed_values = [_("red"), _("orange"), _("blue")];
```

But now you can't retrieve the untranslated values later.

Instead, you could do:

```
$allowed_values = [gettext_noop("red"), gettext_noop("orange"), gettext_noop("blue")];
```

Now everything can work as intended, as long as you implement the rest of this answer.

## How to implement `gettext_noop`

PHP doesn't actually include `gettext_noop` by default. To implement it yourself, add this PHP:

```
function gettext_noop($string)
{
    return $string;
}
```

And in your invocation of `xgettext` on the command-line, include this `--keyword` argument:

```
xgettext --keyword=gettext_noop ...
```